# Is there a function which returns list of client machine names on which a certain domain user profile exists, by taking in input of domain user name

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dns, active-directory, domaincontroller

Is there any way to find out list of machine names in which a domain user profile exists (As a domain user profile can exists in multiple clients) for example I am looking for a function in .net or VC++ which takes in username and his domain details are arguments and returns an array of machine names where the domain user profile exists.

Use Case: I am running a service on each client system connected to domain, this service on each system where ever the domain user profile who requested for password change exists needs to get notified.

Methods Tried:
`Get-ADUser`
`Get-ADComputer`
`Get-CimInstance`
`Get-WmiObject`
I have tried these PowerShell commands but no luck.

Comment: You won't be able to get this information from the domain itself as the profile is local to the machine and only the machine itself can be investigated for the profile. I wouldn't do that from a central script, since the machine may be offline and the result will be unreliable. If you already have a service installed on the computers, why not move the check to the service code? It's already there, can inspect local machine and will run when the machine is online.